# Get Position of a Child Element After a Click Event

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, css

I wanted to write a program that would return a child elements position inside the parent element, but I am having problems. I tried writing the following code but it did not work as expected; Instead of returning the position value it returned the click event. Here is what I tried doing:
(P.S I wanted to solve this problem in raw JS)

```
 (function () {
    // body...

        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble");

        for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {

            x[i].addEventListener('click', function(i){


                console.log(i);


            });



        }

})();
```

HTML:

```
<div id=holder>
<div class="bubble"></div>
<div class="bubble"></div>
<div class="bubble"></div>
<div class="bubble"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are describing the functionality of indexOf in jQuery: https://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: `console.log(i.clientX, i.clientY)`?

Comment: @ControlAltDel No `jQuery` tagged.

Comment: @Kinduser yes, but the code to accomplish this could still be retrieved from jQuery source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to find the position as in the x and y coordinates, you can do the following:

1. make sure the parent div (`#holder`) is positioned
2. Make use of [`offsetLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft) and [`offsetTop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop)

If you are wanting to find position as in array position, you can use

[`Array.prototype.indexOf.call(collection, element)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
(function() {
  // body...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble");

  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

    x[i].addEventListener('click', function(a) { // change the variable name here otherwise you have a local var i conflicting with the loop var i

      console.log(this.offsetLeft, this.offsetTop); // this is the element clicked 
      
      console.log(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(x, this) + 1); // this is the position as an index (plus 1)
    });
  }

})();
```

```css
#holder {
   position:relative;  /* position the parent */
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div class="bubble">1</div>
  <div class="bubble">2</div>
  <div class="bubble">3</div>
  <div class="bubble">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that OP should specify what exactly he wants.

Comment: @Pete Thanks for trying, but this not what I am looking for. I want the child's position inside the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

`i` in your listener's function stands for the whole element and his events, not for the `index` from your `for` loop. Logging it may crash/lag your browser.

I would suggest you to use ES6 treasures with `Array#forEach`.

```js
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('#holder .bubble');

Array.from(elems).forEach((v, i) => v.addEventListener('click', () => {
   console.log(`Child position: ${i}`);
}));
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div class="bubble">a</div>
  <div class="bubble">b</div>
  <div class="bubble">c</div>
  <div class="bubble">d</div>
</div>
```

**However**, if you really want to use `for` loop, do not pass any arguments into your listener's function and change `var i` inside your loop into `let i`.

```js
const x = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble");

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(i);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div class="bubble">a</div>
  <div class="bubble">b</div>
  <div class="bubble">c</div>
  <div class="bubble">d</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this funcion: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect

https://jsfiddle.net/dt1224Ld/

```
(function () {
// body...

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("bubble");

    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {

        x[i].addEventListener('click', function(i){

                    var element = this.getBoundingClientRect();

            console.log(element.top, element.right, element.bottom, element.left);


        });



    }

})();
```